# How can i check if the user input is not string in java

Tags: java, string, validation, input

I want my program to only accept string and prompt a message if the user input is invalid.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Details{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lastname;
        String firstname;
        String middlename;

        System.out.print("Enter Number of passenger : ");
        int passenger = input.nextInt(); 

        for(int x = 0 ; x < passenger ; x++){
            do{
                System.out.print("\nEnter Lastname  :");
                lastname = input.nextLine().trim();

                if(lastname.equals("") || lastname.equals(" "))
                {                 
                    System.out.print("\nEnter Neccessary Details");               
                }
            } while(lastname.isEmpty());

            do{
                System.out.print("\nEnter Firstname : ");
                firstname = input.nextLine();

                if(firstname.equals("") || firstname.equals(" "))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nEnter Neccessary Details");    
                }
            } while(firstname.isEmpty());

            do{
                System.out.print("\nEnter Firstname : ");
                middlename = input.nextLine();

                if(middlename.equals("") || middlename.equals(" "))
                {
                    System.out.print("\nEnter Neccessary Details");    
                }
            }while(middlename.isEmpty());

        }//end of forloop

    }
}
```

i already try this code, at first it works but it shows logical error in the long run. 
And give me an output something like this.

```
    sample output
    Enter Firstname  : // the problem is, it seems has already have an input
    Enter Neccessary Details
    Enter Firstname  :
```

so how can i fix this? 
is there an alternative way to validate string input? please keep it simple i am just a beginner thanks

Comment: Can you show the entire Java class?

Comment: sorry about that, i edited it

Comment: Could you please be more specific on where **specifically** you get errors? What is the input and what error do you get exactly?

Comment: You seem to want to create multiple passengers, not just one. So you surely need multiple `lastName` and `firstName`. So create a class `Passenger` which has a first- and a lastname. Then use a `List<Passenger>` and create a new `Passenger` on every iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()` method to remove all spaces at the beginning and at the end of string and then check if it is empty:

```java
firstname = input.nextLine().trim();
```

**EDIT**: This code seems to work as you need:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Details {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lastname;
        String firstname;
        String middlename;

        System.out.println("Enter Number of passenger : ");
        int passenger = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        for (int x = 0; x < passenger; x++) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Lastname  :");
                lastname = input.nextLine().trim();
                if (lastname.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("\nEnter Neccessary Details");
                }
            } while (lastname.isEmpty());

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Firstname : ");
                firstname = input.nextLine().trim();
                if (firstname.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("\nEnter Neccessary Details");
                }
            } while (firstname.isEmpty());

            do {
                System.out.println("Enter Middlename : ");
                middlename = input.nextLine().trim();
                if (middlename.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Neccessary Details");
                }
            } while (middlename.isEmpty());
        }
    }
}
```

The main change here is that I replaced `System.out.print` with `System.out.println`. `System.out.print` somehow prints only after following `input.nextLine()` read is finished (`System.out.flush` right after printing does not work), so it seems that you press Enter button at the start of your input, and that empty line is read by `Scanner`. Also I added `input.nextLine()` line right after reading `passenger` count, so `Scanner` goes to the next line after reading that number.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Scanner.nextInt` method does not read the newline character in your input,
you need to consume the line after `nextInt`:

```
int passenger = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

This will solve the **it seems it already has an input** problem.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner seems to have problems due using the same one in multiple whiles.
Try using the Scanner in a method like here:

```
public String getInput () {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
return sc.nextLine(); 
}
```

And then use

```
firstname = getInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to create **multiple** passengers, not just **one**. So you surely need multiple `lastName` and `firstName`. So create a class `Passenger` which has a first- and a lastname. Then use a `List<Passenger>` and create a new `Passenger` on every iteration of the outer loop.

So you shoul dhave this:

```
class Passenger {
    String lastname;
    String firstname;
    String middlename;
}
```

Now within your `main` you need a `List<Passenger>`:

```
List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I would suggest to extract a single method from your three do-while-loops, in order to have a single validation-method:

```
String getInput(String kind) {
    String result;
    do{
        System.out.print("\nEnter " + kind + " : ");
        result = input.nextLine().trim();
    } while(result.isEmpty());
}
```

Finally put that into your loop within `main` and create a new `Passenger` on ever iteration, as mentioned above:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Number of passenger : ");
    Integer numPassengers = input.nextInt(); 

    for(int x = 0; x < numPassengers; x++){
        String firstName = getInut("FirstName");
        String lastName = getInput("LastName");
        String MiddleName = getInput("MiddleName");
        passengers.add(new Passenger(firstName, lastName, middleName);
    }
}
```

Of course you need a constructor for your `Passenger`-class that accepts three `String`-args. Furthermore you should never expose public fields as I did above, instead have a public get-method. So your class should look like this:

```
class Passenger {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String middleName;

    public Passenger(String firstName, lastName, middleName) { // constructor
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getFirstName { return this.firstName; }
    public String getLastName { return this.lastName; }
    public String getMiddleName { return this.middleName; }
}
```